# Application restarts automatically

Tags: android, sockets

Im making sockets on WiFi via threads. My app behaves very strange on Android 2.3.4 version, here it randomly restarts; whereas its running fine in versions: 2.3.6 and 4.0. Does anybody have an idea about this problem?

Comment: Post more information, such as relevant code snippets and/or LogCat logs or this will be unanswerable.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have some finish() instruction in some exception try/catch?

Does your application consume a large amount of memory? (can you please check this)

Also, add some profiling tool / bugtracking tool to your application.
I'll suggest you some:

- Bugsense.com
- http://code.google.com/p/acra/ ACRA (to integrate with bugsense if you want)
- Memory Profiling (http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/avoiding-memory-leaks.html + some talks from past google IO)

Comment: thanx for replying, i had used all methods what you said neighter my app consume large amount of memory nor send any bugs on restart.